# Assigining a variable to Python json value

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

If i have a python json and i want to assigned a variable to one of the values in the python json,

```
if booking.hotel.feedback_option == True:
                name = request.GET.get('firstname')
                email= request.GET.get('email')
                values = """
                  {
                    "Name" ="'+str(name)+'",
                    "HasExternalDoubleOptIn": true,
                    "Email"="'+str(email)+'",
                    "CustomFields": [
                    "Checkout=2018-09-07"
                    ]
                  }
                """
                headers = {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
                data = values.encode()
                req = Request('https://api.moosend.com/v3/subscribers/7c343r9ad-er56-4c51-810e-74e27f8505c2/subscribe.json?apikey=77f343914-4t3c-4d61-8435-9346f5b4adf6', data=data, headers=headers)
                response_body  = urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: How is that string being created? It's not standard dictionary syntax and it's also not valid JSON

Comment: @roganjosh please can you view my updated code i just pasted when i try to add variable to Name it give me error, if i just put in a name like "james" it work

Comment: The updated code hasn't changed the string, so my comment remains the same. It looks like you're hard-coding the string yourself? You do not have a dictionary.

Comment: You also don't have JSON, as I said in my first comment. As I asked originally, where is `values` coming from? Or is it something you intend to send?

Comment: the values are to be send to my mailing list as new subcribers. without adding the variable to Name and email and just put in a sting like "Name":"Jim" and " Email":jim@gmail.com" it works it send the values across perfectly and create a new subscriber on my mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, the better way to do this would be to create a python dictionary and then convert to JSON:

```
import json

name = 'Something'
email = 'Something else'

values = {
          "Name": name,
          "HasExternalDoubleOptIn": True,
          "Email": email,
          "CustomFields": [
                    "Checkout=2018-09-07"
                    ]
          }

values = json.dumps(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first value in the dictionary initializer is bad syntax - should be something line
`”Name”: str(name),`
Similarly
`”Email”: str(email),`